# PDF Watermark with: Transparency, underlined, bold and Italicized Text Ghostscript and Php

Tags: php, fpdf, ghostscript

I am trying to watermark( with text ) pdf with ghostscript. Earlier, I added page numbers via ghostscript, even text based watermark in pdf but transparency and watermark above and below the content seem to be an issue and for that i have had failed attempts with Postscript's PDFMARK extension. Below is the ps code(In the body of **EndPage**), i have deliberately tried to write the text instead of Stroke in order to allow bold, italics and underlines. I am considering to change from php to any other language if it offers a free alternative to this.

```
 /Helvetica 44 selectfont 
  (Shadab Hussain Watermark on Test)
  dup       
  stringwidth pop
  currentpagedevice /PageSize get 0 get 
  exch sub 2 div 
  currentpagedevice /PageSize get 1 get 2 div moveto 
  show
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do transparency in PostScript, because it isn't supported in the graphics model. This is one of the major differences between PostScript and PDF.

Ghostscript does have some extensions to the PostScript imaging model which will allow **some** use of PDF transparency from PostScript, but it's non-trivial. You should (using the latest HEAD from the Ghostscript Git repository) look at ghostpdl/examples/transparency_example.ps for an example of using transparency from PostScript. Note that these extensions are **totally** Ghostscript-specific and will not work with any other PostScript interpreter.

As regards 'above' and 'below' the content. You either execute the PostScript program on BeginPage, in which case it is laid down before the PDF content, and may be overwritten by it (hint: many PDF files start by drawing a white rectangle covering the page), or you execute the PostScript program on EndPage (both is also possible), in which case it overwrites the already drawn content.